# Integrating sin(2x) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-integration

**SITUATION:**

I'm new to MATLAB and currently learning how to integrate expressions. I seem to be inserting correct code to integrate simple functions like x^2 or sin(x).

The code I am entering to integrate sin(x) is:

```
syms x

int(sin(x))

ans=

-cos(x)
```

**QUESTION:**

I'm trying to integrate the function sin(2x). My code is below along with the answer I'm receiving. Could someone explain why MATLAB is displaying this incorrect answer and how I can fix my code.

Code Entered:

```
syms x

int(sin(2*x))
```

Incorrect Answer being displayed:

```
ans = 

sin(x)^2
```

The answer I'm looking for is

```
 (-1/2)*cos(2x)+c
```

Comment: You can use the function [`simple`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simple.html) to view you your solution in a variety of formats. One of them is the equivalent `1/2 - cos(2*x)/2`.

Answer (score 3):

It's not incorrect.

```
cos(2x) = 1 - 2 * sin^2(x)
```

So:

```
(-1/2) * cos(2x) = sin^2(x) - (1/2)
```

MATLAB gave you an equivalent answer.